# Change ossec(wazuh) agent profiles via saltstack

Tags: salt-stack, ossec, wazuh

I'm trying to modify the `<config-profile>` section of a `ossc.conf` file, including a grains content.

something like:

```
ossec-profiles:
  - profile1
  - profile2
```

and I want to modify the section `<config-profile>` from

```
<config-profile>centos, centos7</config-profile>
```

to

```
<config-profile>centos, centos7, profile1, profile2</config-profile>
```

in the `ossec.conf` file

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using [file.replace](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.file.html#salt.states.file.replace) module which makes you able to change a text in a file based on a pattern. So in your case you can do the following:

You need to select the pattern as regex group so you can use it later as shown below

```yaml
configure_ossec:
  file.replace:
    - name: /path/to/ossec.conf
    - pattern: '((<config-profile>.*?)[^<]*)'
    - repl: {{ '\\1, ' +  pillar['ossec-profiles'] | join(', ') }}
```

Or you might use this pattern to match only whatever inside `config-profile` tags then you will be able to call it again in the `repl` parameter:

```regex
(?<=<config-profile>)(.*)(?=<\/config-profile>)
```

> Note: As `pillar['ossec-profiles']` should return a list of profiles
>   then you have to use the join filter in order to separate the values
>   with comma as a delimiter

And finally the output expected to be something like this:

```
     Changes:   
              ----------
              diff:
                  --- 
                  +++ 
                  @@ -1 +1 @@
                  -<config-profile>centos, centos7</config-profile>
                  +<config-profile>centos, centos7, profile1, profile2</config-profile>
```

Comment: Yes, this could be a starting point, but it not so easy because we don't have only centos7 servers.

Comment: @MarcelloPercoco answer updated, you can check it now

Comment: Perfect, after your first hint i'ver reached the same solution!
Thanks.